# In a pandas dataframe column, remove last 4 digit if it's 2017

Tags: string, pandas, text, replace, strip

In a pandas dataframe, there is a column X, with numbers like 12342017, 23456782017, WC456123, ER2017124. 
I want to remove the last four digit if it's '2017'

So, my desired output should be 1234,2345677,WC45612,ER2017124

Comment: you should probably show your code in which you are dealing with the pandas dataframe so that people make the correct suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `$` for regex for end of string, also if possible mix numbers with strings first convert to strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['12342017', '23456782017', 'WC456123', 'ER2017124']})

df['X'] = df['X'].astype(str).str.replace('2017$','')
print (df)
           X
0       1234
1    2345678
2   WC456123
3  ER2017124
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. So, if I put $ in the front, it means leading 4 digits right? What if I want to get rid of "2017" counting from the second last digit to the left?